# Set Windows Server idle task

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I want to execute a batch file when the computer has been idle (no keyboard or mouse inputs) for one minute using Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2012. I've had a go but the task doesn't seem to ever run. I've created the same task on my local computer and it works fine.

The task is set to run for a separate user to the Admin but it's run with the highest privileges.

Here are my triggers:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NxPimjK.png]

Here are my conditions:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/o4pcnDl.png]

Comment: Are you using 2012, or 2012 R2? Which Windows version is on your local computer?

Comment: I'm using 2012 R2.